# Google Play Music way too fast, accelerated

Tags: google-chrome, music, mp3

I turn to Google Play to listen to my mp3's most of the time.  lately, on my desktop, they are accelerated when I'm using Google Play, through chrome.  They sound like chipmunks!

If I play the mp3's on my hard disk through movie player, they play at the correct speed.  Any idea why this is?

Comment: What chrome are you running? Have you tried using Chromium?

Comment: No, I haven't, but it does work fine in firefox.  I'm using Version 27.0.1453.110.  I just found the report an issue link, and am reporting it, but I doubt I'll get a response.

Comment: never mind.  it fixed itself in the latest chrome update.  ....super obnoxious.  I wonder though, if it's related to pulse audio.

Comment: @Pentax which version of chrome fixed it? I am experiencing this exact issue.

Comment: In case anyone is following, I narrowed it down to the fact that I am using the html5 vs flash option. Once I switch to the old-school flash version, it works... (sorry about the thread hijacking, I'll ask my own question if I can't find anything more).

Comment: great!  sorry, I haven't checked this lately.  I'm glad it's fixed.  Flash is such fail, what more can be said?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

fixed in an automatic update using the ubuntu updater.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue using the latest Chromium on Ubuntu 13.04
Changing back to Flash from HTML5 solved the issue for me.

Super obnoxious though and I would love to use HTML5 instead.

Comment: Chrome receives updates more frequently. Maybe it will be fixed with the next Chromium update as well.